# Tracking azure redis via end-to-end transaction in application insights

Tags: c#, azure, redis

I am using Azure Application Insights to track operations in request.

I implemented redis, I stored data into key and I put expiration time to 1day. This is test method:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<FoodDescriptionModel>> SearchIngredientAsync(string name)
{
    _redisCache.TryGetValue("FoodDescriptionModelCollection", out IReadOnlyCollection<FoodDescriptionModel> cached);

    return cached.Where(x => x.LongDescription.Contains(name)).ToList() as IReadOnlyCollection<FoodDescriptionModel>;
}
```

Which is definitely taking data from cache.
Problem is it that end-to-end transaction in azure portal shows access to database for that request:
[image]

Why? On other side when I check redis amount of gets is increasing:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to tell what kind of Redis client you are using but does not look like StackExchange or ServiceStack. It would be helpful if you provided the type of `_redisCache`

Application Insights does not track calls to Redis automatically yet (with any client), but you can track them manually, here is an example for `StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.StringSet`:

```
private async Task<bool> StringSetTrackedAsync(RedisKey key, string value)
{
    var dependency = new DependencyTelemetry()
    {
        Type = "Redis",
        Name = "SetStringAsync"
    };
    dependency.Properties["key"] = key;
    using (telemetryClient.StartOperation(dependency))
    {
        var result = await cache.StringSetAsync(key, value);
        dependency.Success = result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

You may add details such as Redis host or remove things you don't want to be in the telemetry.

[Here is how it looks like in the viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0qlJ.jpg)

Comment: It is stack exchange. I’ll update code with client. When I use redis console i can see key is there and for above code to work it can only read from cache as you can see but still shows like it did trip to database... how if there is no code for trip to database..

Comment: found the problem, ci pipeline i was changing something and missed a bit, all good